# How to mount external µSD card partition filesystems on Moto g Power?

Tags: external-sd, motorola-moto-g, partitions, ext4

A µSD card has several partitions, but the phone mounts only the vfat partition, not the ext4 partitions.

I see that there are existing internal ext4 filesystems, so it can handle that type.

Is there something I need to do to allow the ext4 µSD card partitions to be mounted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create and use multiple partitions on external SD card with different filesystems (Ext4, exFAT, NTFS)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219992/how-to-create-and-use-multiple-partitions-on-external-sd-card-with-different-fil)