# Resize /data on stock recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, partitions

I'm on the BL6000Pro (with Magisk) which has no custom recovery (like TWRP) that I know of.
I run CAOS11 on it but the `/system` partition is already full while the `/data` partition is huge and empty.

I'd like to shrink `/data` and expand `/system`.
However, all solutions to shrinking `/data` require a custom recovery to manipulate the unmounted `/data` partition.
I can manipulate `/system` via `fastboot resize-logical-partition system {{size}}` but not `/data` because `/data` is not a logical partition.
In the stock recovery I have no `adb` access (`adb devices` says "unauthorized") while I have adb access in the ROM.

**Question:**
Is there a way to shrink `/data` without a custom recovery?

I think this question applies generically to any device that has no custom recovery and might therefore be of (somewhat) larger value to the community.

**Edit:**
Here's an excerpt from `fastboot getvar all`

```
(bootloader) partition-size:userdata:0x3A05FF8000
(bootloader) partition-size:sdc:0x3B96000000
(bootloader) partition-size:misc:0x80000
(bootloader) partition-size:boot:0x2000000
(bootloader) partition-size:super:0x140000000
(bootloader) partition-size:metadata:0x2000000
(bootloader) partition-size:vendor:0x29817000
(bootloader) partition-size:system:0x100000000
(bootloader) super-partition-name:super
(bootloader) is-logical:para:no
(bootloader) is-logical:userdata:no
(bootloader) is-logical:sdc:no
(bootloader) is-logical:misc:no
(bootloader) is-logical:boot:no
(bootloader) is-logical:super:no
(bootloader) is-logical:metadata:no
(bootloader) is-logical:vendor:yes
(bootloader) is-logical:system:yes
```

Comment: *"you can delete some non-essential dynamic partitions, such as the product partition"* (search for `lpmake`) what is *'fastboot getvar partition-size:super'* total size, do you really think it's necessary to shrink userdata partition?

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for the response. I added the excerpt to the question.
I already deleted `product` to fit in the CAOS11 `/system`.
I already increased `/system`but only marginally via fastbootd, I don't see another way to increasing `/system`but I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: your super partition is almost full, without custom recovery or root you can increase system 359 MB only

Comment: @alecxs I managed to create a full backup via mtkclient.
I'm not sure what to do next. My only idea is to edit the scatter file (increase `partition_size`of `super`, also reduce the size of `userdata`) and flash the `super` partition again via SP Flash. Is that allowed? Also I'm not sure what to do with `pgpt` and `sgpt`. I'd greatly appreciate your advice.

Comment: Hi, sounds like a plan. you should be able to modify pgpt+sgpt files on pc with partitioning tool

Comment: try something like `parted pgpt.bin unit B print` on linux PC. here is a example usage for [parted](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219992)

Comment: just to clarify: by edit scatter you mean calculate new size + new offset for all partitions in line of course. + pgpt must edited too, both steps are required in combination (write new partitions in new scatter + write new pgpt) imho

Comment: here is how to (not) restore pgpt https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4536929