# How to access all partitions of a USB drive OR how to choose which partition is displayed in file manager?

Tags: partitions, usb-on-the-go

I'm on a OnePlus 8T on Android 13, and I've recently purchased a fingerprint encrypted USB. The way the USB works, is it has a Public and a Secure partition. When you insert the USB, only the Public partition is visible, and then when you scan your fingerprint, the Secure partition becomes available.

The problem is, Android seems to only ever show 1 partition of a USB in the file manager, which in my case is always the Public partition, but I want to be able to access the Secure partition on my phone.

I believe the way I can go about this would be to either make the phone show all partitions of the USB, rather than just 1, or somehow make it so that the 1 partition being shown is the Secure one rather than the Public one.

I have no idea how I would go about doing this, can anyone help (or know anything else I could try)? Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that you can not use a fingerprint to encrypt data? The only think you can do with a fingerprint is to check it and allow/disallow access. But the actual data remains unencrypted. If i is encrypted then the encryption key is also saved in the USB stick. Unless the stick contains a secure element the encryption key can be extracted without big problems. If the stick was cheaper than ~500 USD then most likely it will be not very secure. I would not store any data you want to keep private on it and rely on the "encryption".

Comment: lol the fingerprint itself is not the encryption key, it just allows you to unencrypt the 256 bit AES encrypted data using the firmware key. The security of the USB is not relevant to the question.

Comment: (stock) Android always mounts only first partition

Comment: Yeah, so is there any way to change that / make the "first partition" the Secure one?

Comment: [How to use multiple partitions on external SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219992/218526)