# How do I make my android ROM auto-mounts and activate a swap partition in my sd card?

Tags: mount, ram, swap

I have created a swap partition via **GNOME Disks** in my SD Card and I found that my Android system doesn't detect it until I used **Aparted** to activate it but still It is not persistent after a reboot and I don't know how to recognize the path of my swap partition according to Android But I knew the path of my SD card via **Aparted**: `/dev/block/mmcblk1` so I don't know how to modify `fstab.qcom` for permanently using the swap partition in my SD card.

Comment: Do `mkswap` once and then you just need to run `swapon` on every boot: [How to run an executable on boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526) // Similar question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/78177/218526. // Why using SD card as SWAP partition is a bad idea: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220042/218526

Comment: "swapon" just doesn't work alone as It needs a file argument and the android "swapon" is limited than another.

Comment: or tell me how to use mkswap/swapon with a swap partition I created on my sdcard?

Comment: It's obvious that you need to provide partition block device path to the `swapon` command. You can simply hard-code the path: `/dev/block/mmcblk1p[N]` in the boot script. Or to be on safe side, provide the UUID of the partition to `swapon`: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapon.8.html. Build a full `swapon` binary from `util-linux` package. Or do some scripting to get the block device path from UUID and provide that to the Android's minimal `swapon`.

Comment: yeah, I discovered that the path is `/dev/block/mmcblk1p1` and swapon is working now but not persistent upon reboot. What about `fstab.qcom` I  have added `/dev/block/mmcblk1p1          none            swap    sw              0       0` to it and it didn't work.